# Unable to partition my 1 TB hard drive in 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

- I brought Dell laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 with a 1TB HDD.

  - I want to install windows 7 as well (dual boot).
    When I tried to partition my hard drive with Gparted, I am not able to drag the free space.

Please help me to create partition on Ubuntu 14.04 for dual-booting with Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to resize a mounted partition which is not possible. You will have to boot from an Ubuntu Live USB to resize that partition since you cant unmount it.

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to make the Live USB. then boot up your laptop from this Live USB and use gparted to resize the partition.